# Upload field that is fully managed by JavaScript (no upload to a server)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sapui5

I want to add an import functionality to a SAPUI5 application. I don't need to upload the file to a server, since I only want to handle the file on the client-side. The FileUploader control that is supplied with SAPUI5 doesn't seem to support that.

Answer (score 0):

One can disable the automatic upload by not setting the `uploadOnChange` property to true, and then adding a `change` handler to the control. The `change` handler has access to the uploaded files via `oEvent.getParameters().files`,
and can process the uploaded files. When the form that is inside the FileUploader control is never submitted, it won't try to upload the files.

```xml
<mvc:View
    controllerName="app.controller.Main"
    xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
    displayBlock="true">
    <Shell id="shell">
        <App id="app">
            <pages>
                <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
                    <content>
                        <unified:FileUploader id="ui5-uploader"/>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("app.controller.Main", {
        onAfterRendering: function() {
            var uploader = this.getView().byId("ui5-uploader");
            uploader.attachChange(function(oEvent) {
                oEvent.getParameters().files[0].text().then(
                    function(sContent) {
                        console.log(sContent);
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        
    });
});
```